# Is it possible to deactivate preinstalled windows software and install it on a mac using Boot Camp?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, operating-systems, boot-camp

There is a program that I would like to download for mac, but it didn't make a version specifically for mac yet. I have a PC with windows 7 on it (including the license key). Is it possible to deactivate it or put it on a memory stick and install it onto mac?

Comment: If its an OEM installation, no, its not possible.  There are virtual machines that Microsoft offers use one of those and there is virtual box which is free.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the above comment, it is almost certainly not possible if it is OEM software.

However, there may be a solution for your specific program.  Also vendors often offer upgrades at significantly reduced prices for OEM software, and every now and then it's worth it.

I would recommend Google as well as the vendor's website, and search for something like `upgrade OEM license`.